# How to define a type for string | number?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have a map function and my function's parameter's type is an array of strings or number. I'm defining it like:

```
(param: (string | number)[]) => ...
```

however I want to beauty it like:

```
(param: StringOrNumber)[]) => ...
```

since I'm using that param in many functions and found that pipeline in middle decreases readibility. Is there a way to do that by default in Typescript or am I need to define a custom type for that?

Comment: I'd say write a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases): `type StringOrNumber = string | number;`, but that is "defining a custom type" so I'm not sure if that meets your needs or not.  Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwPLwHIFcC2ARhPFALxQDOCKqUAPlMvkfANwBQAxgPbJVQAzMuyhQAFGACG8SXgBcsamky5CxANoBdAJRkAfFCky8AOjySwYgG76ooSNyE3SLqACIqSNG6gB+KFYmwNwAqmCQ8ADCkhQQYroKgcEAYogAHhAAJvHarEA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define a custom type for this, like `type StringOrNumber = string | number`. However, if you include a custom type such as this in a declaration file (eg. in a file named `types.d.ts`, where the `.d.ts` suffix indicates to the TypeScript compiler that it is a declaration file) somewhere in your project, then that type will be globally available in the other files in your project.

I would recommend reading up on declaration files in the documentation here, though it's not super clear.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a new type and use it everywhere, that's totally fine, or you could use `Array<string | number>`, what is more readable IMO.